# C++ project structure with foreign libraries

Tags: c++, xcode, git

I am a little bit confused on how to structure my C++ project with a foreign library that I need to use. The library is [Simon Gog's SDSL](https://github.com/simongog/sdsl-lite). So, as you can see, it has bunch of different folders in it. I understand that the source files are in `lib` and header files are in `include`.

Now when I create my new project that wants to use this library, how should this project's structure look like? Is it enough to just put these 2 folders, `lib` and `include` in the project's root so that the library can function?

And after that, when I write my own header and source files, where should I put those? Do I put them in the same `lib` and `include` folder where the foreign library is, or should I use another folder?

I was thinking to structure it something like this:

```
|--> MyProjectName;
        |--> dependencies
                |--> lib // foreign library's .cpp files
                |--> include // foreign library's .h files
        |--> lib // my program's .cpp files
        |--> include // my program's .h files
```

Is this OK? Could you suggest me some adequate structure for my project so it makes sense and can be easily exportable to git?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your folders. In my case i always have sepereted files in folders, also i am using more files with functions.